# How do I find the eigenvalues in this sequence?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of all infinite sequences of real numbers, and let $T : V → V$ be the linear transformation that “deletes two terms” of a sequence, so $T (x_0, x_1, x_2, . . .) = (x_2, x_3, x_4 . . .).$ Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$ .

Comment: note that $T(1,1,1,...)=(1,1,1,...)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the condition is, for a non zero eigenvalue  $\lambda$

$$\forall k, x_{k+2}=\lambda x_{k}$$

forcing the structure of an associated eigenvector to be:

$$(x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots)=(x_0,x_1,\lambda x_0,\lambda x_1,\lambda^2 x_0,\lambda^2 x_1,\cdots) \ \ \ (1)$$

$$=x_0\underbrace{(1,0,\lambda,0,\lambda^2,0,\lambda^3}_{},\cdots)+x_1\underbrace{(0,1,0,\lambda,0,\lambda^2,0,\lambda^3,\cdots)}_{V_{\lambda}}$$

Therefore, there is a continuous spectrum (all reals $\lambda$ are eigenvalues), with, for each $\lambda$, 2 eigenvectors $U_{\lambda},V_{\lambda}$, decomposition (1) placing in evidence the structure of the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$.

Note the particular case of eigenvectors associated with eigenvalue 0 (which constitute a basis of the kernel) $U_0=(1,0,0,0....)$ (one followed by an infinity of zeros) and $V_0=(0,1,0,0....)$ (zero, one, followed by an infinity of zeros). Thus the kernel has dimension 2.